# Salesforce Process Builder

Tags: process-builder

I have an object called Milestones on the Case.  At a certian stage of the Case 5-8 milestones are created.

What I need to do now is if a value is selected or a field checked in the First Milestone for the Case that this value moves to the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th...

Is this possible with the Process Builder and if so  what Action Type do I need to use

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it is not just a Process in the Process builder that needs to be done but a flow that will get the information of the siblings and do the update.  The process will just trigger that flow.